# Stretch images if needed only up to 20%

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

We have an image gallery with responsive sizes, using a [ready made React gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery).

The images need to fit into a container with predefined, responsive height and width, but the images we're getting from the server are in different proportions and sizes: sometimes the proportions don't match, and sometimes the image is not big enough to even fill the container.

The product requirement is that an image should only be scaled *up to 20% of the original image size* to fit the container:

[image]
[image]

*How do I even refer to the original image size in CSS?* If I use percentage that would be referring to the container size... I stumbled upon `Object-fit` but it's not supported on IE.

I thought of using inline styles from JS but that would be complicated since this is responsive and the sizes would need to be calculated again on each window resize.

Thank you.

Comment: You are taking images as `background` or with `<img>` tag?

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is some css like `max-width:120%; max-height:120%` - but I know in the past, specifying such things in images can be hit and miss

Comment: I'm currently using `<img>` tags though I don't think it's the issue here. Indeed, `max-width:120%; max-height:120` don't do the trick - I need to refer to the actual image dimensions, not to the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two cases :

1. If you are taking `<img>` inside you container

```css
.container
{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}
.container img
{
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://regmedia.co.uk/2015/11/16/help_2.jpg">
</div>
```

2. If you are taking image as `background` of the container

```css
.container
{
  background-image: url('https://regmedia.co.uk/2015/11/16/help_2.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width:80%;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: You want a responsive image for your container. So that's what i did. Now it's us to you how much you want to scale your image.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not looking for a responsive image - I need to scale the image _depending on its dimensions_.